# accessibilityElementsHidden for OS X? How to protect my app's UI internals from stealing eyes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I need to protect my WebView's URL (make it unavailable for Accessibility Inspector).
Don't write me that all traffic can be sniffed anyway and etc. I am an reverse-engineer, I know all it enough, and I know what I want.
I need to protect my WebView's URL, point.

URL of WebView is storing not in WebView, but nested in 1st child of its child, with `WebAccessibilityObjectWrapper` class and "HTML content" type.
Unfortunately, `WebAccessibilityObjectWrapper` class is Apple's "closed" class and we can't extend it.

**iOS (from 5.0+) has wonderful feature, `accessibilityElementsHidden`, which solves my problem.

But OS X doesn't.**

My solutions:

1. Override `NSAccessibilityChildrenAttribute` for WebView with passing empty array for its value. It really protects from walking through "children" property in Inspector. But, unfortunately, not from Inspector's "point" feature.
2. Programmatically find "HTML content" in Accessibility children and work with it. Unfortunately, we need to do it after every URL load and where are no special event for this, it's too dirty.

How to solve it more elegant?

Comment: Some ideas to test, not sure what's available in MacOS : `.isAccesibilityElement` set to NO/false , `.accesibilityTraits` set to none, `accessibilityElements` of the parent view set to contain only desired views (the last approach may be really hard since it's a webview)

Comment: Why do you hate blind people? (Seriously. This is who accessibility is for. Disabling it will make your app impossible for them to use.)

Comment: @Kamil.S Thanks for accesibilityTraits and partly for accessibilityElements, will test.

Comment: @duskwuff 1) Life of blind people unbearable anyway, my app is small change, too small. If you think Apple really helps blind people it is nonsense. 2) I do not want disable it at all, I only want hide WebView's URL. If it is impossible and I need to disable it at all - it isn't my fault, it is Apple's fault. 3) If I will allow burglars still my content, I will cannot make apps at all because I requiring at least a food. :)

Comment: @Rou1997 I'm sure you are aware your app is still prone to network packet sniffing and the url could probably still be found this way.

Comment: @Kamil.S I making different solutions for different stealing ways.

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility protocol in iOS and macOS are slightly different. In iOS making a "view" transparent to the VO technology is simpler than in macOS.

Properties you can play with are:

- Accessibility element: that you set to `false`;
- Accessibility role: that you need to set to `none`;
- Accessibility role description: you could set to "";

The problem is that when a view is disabled as an accessibility element, all of its subviews become visible. One example of this is the `NSButton`. Simply disabling the "external" button object, i.e.:

```
let b = NSButton(...)
// setup your b 
b.setAccessibilityElement(false)
```

doesn't solve the problem. VO still can see the button cell.

Making an UI element hidden for VO is not trivial, but it is tricky. You need to play a while understanding the very nature of the specific object you would like to hide.